# Bloquear salvar dados repetidos

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Como verifico no controller, se já existe um e-mail cadastrado no banco mongoose e assim, bloqueio salva-lo novamente?

Comment: Olha não sei se te ajuda pois não tenho muita experiência com `NodeJs` .Mas tenta fazer uma consulta enviando o email com parâmetro se retornar alguma coisa diferente de `null ` você faz a ação de bloquear o botão

Comment: Também não tenho experiência com NodeJs e Mongo, mas não teria algo como UNIQUE no Mongo e que a gente consegui-se setar para o campo email?

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é estabelecer um índice único no campo. Isso pode ser feito adicionando `unique: true` para a definição do campo no schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true }
  // ...
});
```

Você pode ler sobre essa feature aqui: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique

E sobre índices únicos no MongoDB aqui:
http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/index-unique/

Os saves e updates vão falhar sem outras mudanças no seu código quando valores duplicados forem ser inseridos. A resposta do Vitor é válida, mas passível a race conditions (e se um usuário com e-mail duplicado for inserido entre o `find` e o `save`?).

Você pode então tratar o erro que o MongoDB vai retornar em valores duplicados:

```
// Ou dê match no código do erro (E11000)
if(_.contains(err.message, 'duplicate key error') &&
   _.contains(err.message, 'users.$email')) {
  err = new Error('This email is already registered');
  err.status = 400;
}

throw err;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um [validador](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) que só permite a inclusão ou alteração de um usuário se o endereço de e-mail não existe no coleção:

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, done) {
    var User = mongoose.model('User')

    // Check only when it is a new user or when email field is modified
    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('email')) {
        User.find({ email: email }).exec(function (err, users) {
            done(!err && users.length === 0)
        })
    } else done(true);
}, 'Email já registrado.');
```

No *controller* verifique o erro após tentar salvar o usuário:

```
/* Create new user. */
exports.new = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.save(function(err){
    if (err & err.errors.email) 
      return res.status(400).json({message: err.errors.email.type});
    else 
      return res.sendStatus(201);
    }
  });
};
```